# Unix2Dos Sub-directories with file rename

Tags: bash, shell-script

I'm looking for the best way to handle essentially performing a **Unix2Dos** on all files with a certain extension `.nux`.

I actually want to rename the extension to `.nun`.

Right now my code manually pushes into each hard coded directory to achieve this but I would think / hope that there's a cleaner way to do this. A code that could recursively dive into every folder below `/testpath/temp/` and "rename" the `.nux` file(s) to `.nun` and change the Linux line endings to Windows line endings.

**BASH VERSION 3.2.57(2)-release**

```
pushd /testpath/temp/xyz
if [[ -f PRXYZ.NUX ]]
  then
    sed 's/$/\r/' PRXYZ.NUX > PRXYZ.NUN
    rm PRXYZ.NUX
fi
popd

pushd /testpath/temp/abc
if [[ -f PRABC.NUX ]]
  then
    sed 's/$/\r/' PRABC.NUX > PRABC.NUN
    rm PRABC.NUX
fi
popd

pushd /testpath/temp/lmn
if [[ -f PRLMN.NUX ]]
  then
    sed 's/$/\r/' PRLMN.NUX > PRLMN.NUN
    rm PRLMN.NUX
fi
popd
```

Comment: Look up `find` and its `exec` option. Something like `find . -name "*.nux" -exec sed [...]` should do what you want. This command is inclompete, and completing it is left as an exercise to the reader ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For newline conversions, there's [`dos2unix`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/unix2dos) package, available on linux systems, providinf `unix2dos`, which you can use to convert the files, instead of using `sed`:

> `-ascii`   Convert only line breaks. This is the default conversion mode.

and

> `-l, --newline` Add additional newline.
>
> **dos2unix**: Only DOS line breaks are changed to two Unix line breaks. In
>   Mac mode only Mac line breaks are changed to two Unix line breaks.
>
> **unix2dos**: Only Unix line breaks are changed to two DOS line breaks. In
>   Mac mode Unix line breaks are changed to two Mac line breaks.

And, as per Panki's comment, you can use `find`  to grab the files, rename them and convert:

```
find /testpath/temp/ -type f -name "*.NUX" \
    -exec sh -c 'unix2dos "$1"; mv "$1" "${1%.NUX}.NUN"' _ {} \;
```

Comment: Where did you find that neat underscore-trick? I don't see it in the manpage?

Comment: @markgraf, check this out http://mywiki.wooledge.org/UsingFind#Complex_actions